# ICECAST streaming two different playlists

Tags: icecast

I already modified my icecast.xml

```
<listen-socket>
    <port>8000</port>
</listen-socket>
<listen-socket>
    <port>8001</port>
</listen-socket>
<fileserve>2</fileserve>
```

I want to send one playlist thru port 8000 (I'm already doing so)
But I need to send a different playlist from port 8001

The problem is that I hear the stream from port 8000 on 8001 and not my second playlist.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to have a look at [this nice explanation](http://liveice.sourceforge.net/understanding.html).

Basically what this means is that you don't need to mess with port numbers, as Icecast maps streams to virtual paths on *one* web server.

As an example you could then have:

- `http://stream.example.org:8000/stream1.ogg`
- `http://stream.example.org:8000/stream2.ogg`

Or if those streams are unrelated you could also access the very same streams as:

- `http://radio1.example.org:8000/stream1.ogg`
- `http://radio2.example.org:8000/stream2.ogg`

As long as both hostnames resolve to the IP address of your Icecast server.

Comment: OOooohh, hello!. Now,how does ICECAST generate the stream1.ogg stream2.ogg stream3.ogg and how do I decipher this? On the nice example you suggested, there's only one source, I'v got 6 sources, So How does icecast determine the rout of every signal?

Comment: The source client specifies the target mountpoint. Icecast then makes this available under the given path. Also note that if you plan on 6 parallel streams, you should adjust the global source client limit and restart Icecast.

Comment: Thank You, so let me see if I understood right... If I have let's say on my home computer some audio files to stream and I'm using butt, on my home computer the settings should be:  Address: 000.111.222.333 - Port: 8000 - Password: xxxxxxxx -  IceCast mountpoint: home -  IceCast user: blabla
And, on my office I have another audio files that I whant to stream for the store ambient, than my workplace computer using butt shuod have the settings...  Address: 000.111.222.333 - Port: 8000 - Password: xxxxxxxx -   IceCast mountpoint: work - IceCast user: blabla...  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, please note that you may need to have a slash at the front of the mountpoint name, this may depend on the source client. Some need `/home` others will need `home`. If something doesn't work as expected, look at the Icecast `error.log`.

Comment: Got it.. Its working!
Thank You for you time and patience.